# Image processing effect time consuming

Tags: android, image-processing

I apply sepia effect on image but when I click on button to apply its done but  after 90 sec .

```
public static Bitmap effect(Bitmap src, int depth, double red, double green, double blue) 
{

        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        final double GS_RED = 0.3;
        final double GS_GREEN = 0.59;
        final double GS_BLUE = 0.11;

        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;


        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {

                pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);

                A = Color.alpha(pixel);             
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                G = Color.green(pixel);
                B = Color.blue(pixel);

                B = G = R = (int)(GS_RED * R + GS_GREEN * G + GS_BLUE * B);

                R += (depth * red);
                if(R > 255) { R = 255; }

                G += (depth * green);
                if(G > 255) { G = 255; }

                B += (depth * blue);
                if(B > 255) { B = 255; }
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
                   }}

    return bmOut;
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem more clearly.  Are you saying that this function takes too long?

Comment: I would advise using `getPixels()` and `setPixels()` instead, and manipulating the resulting array in between, rather than processing each pixel one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it appears that you are using the sample code on my blog: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/image-processing-photography-sepia-toning-effect/
The article means to demonstrate the how to implement the algorithm, so it certainly doesn't mention anything else.

As for performance problem, I suggest:

1. If you develop under Application Level (Java code..), use `getPixels()` `setPixels()` and manipulate the two-dimensional array. Well, in this sepia-toning, it might be up to only 5-10 seconds on emulator, on real device it might be 3 seconds.
2. It's preferable to do all image processing stuffs on NDK (like creating image processing library..), it will process much faster.

Anyway, have fun!

Comment: welcome buddy, anyway, you might want to mark answer as it's acceptable for you, it's for others having the same problem the find the solution. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You could just place a semi-transparent orange/yellow rectangle ontop, it will achieve the same effect as your code above and you wont have to worry about processing time, you are using a mobile phone after all.

Its not solving your problem but its also no analysing and manipulating every pixels colour, your only issue would be saving the resulting image however this is done in a similar way